# objective c how to remove the item in second and third text field based on select the first text field item

Tags: ios, objective-c, pickerview

I have one UIPickerview. I have a json response. I have a three text fields. If user select the first text field display picker view then user select the particular item. And second and third text field also same. My requirement Is if user select the the particular item in first picker view second and third picker view does not showing the item. And second and third also same.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A+",@"A-",@"B+",@"B-",@"O+",@"O-", nil];

bloodGroup = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, logoImg.frame.origin.y+logoImg.frame.size.height+45, screenWidth-20, 50)];

bloodGroup.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

bloodGroup.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

bloodGroup.placeholder = @"Please Select Your Option";

bloodGroup.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:bloodGroup];

txtField1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, ansField1.frame.origin.y+ansField1.frame.size.height+45, screenWidth-20, 50)];

txtField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

txtField1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

txtField1.placeholder = @"Please Select Your Option";

txtField1.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:txtField1];

txtField2 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, ansField2.frame.origin.y+ansField2.frame.size.height+45, screenWidth-20, 50)];

txtField2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

txtField2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

txtField2.placeholder = @"Please Select Your Option";

txtField2.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:txtField2];

myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

[myPickerView setDataSource: self];

[myPickerView setDelegate: self];

myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

bloodGroup.inputView = myPickerView;

bloodGroup.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

// txtField1

txtField1.inputView = myPickerView;

txtField1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

txtField2.inputView = myPickerView;

txtField2.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

return 1;

}

else if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected){

return 1;

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

return 1;

}

return 0;

}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

return [dataArray count];

}

else if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected)

{

return [dataArray count];

}

else if (!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

return [dataArray count];

}

return 0;

}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected)

{

return dataArray[row];

}

else if((!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) && (isGenderGroupFieldSelected))

{

return dataArray[row];

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

return dataArray[row];

}

return 0;

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

bloodGroup.text = dataArray[row];

}

else if((!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) && (isGenderGroupFieldSelected))

{

txtField1.text = dataArray[row];

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

txtField2.text= dataArray[row];

}

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

if (textField == bloodGroup) {

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = YES;

}

else if (textField == txtField1){

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;

isGenderGroupFieldSelected = YES;

}

else if (textField == txtField2) {

isGenderGroupFieldSelected = NO;

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;

}

[myPickerView reloadAllComponents];

}
```

Comment: Please format the code.

Comment: @vadian sure. if you have any idea pls tell me about my Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-(void)viewDidLoad
{

dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A+",@"A-",@"B+",@"B-",@"O+",@"O-", nil];

bloodGroup = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, logoImg.frame.origin.y+logoImg.frame.size.height+45, screenWidth-20, 50)];

bloodGroup.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

bloodGroup.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

bloodGroup.placeholder = @"Please Select Your Option";

bloodGroup.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:bloodGroup];

txtField1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, ansField1.frame.origin.y+ansField1.frame.size.height+45, screenWidth-20, 50)];

txtField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

txtField1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

txtField1.placeholder = @"Please Select Your Option";

txtField1.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:txtField1];

txtField2 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, ansField2.frame.origin.y+ansField2.frame.size.height+45, screenWidth-20, 50)];

txtField2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

txtField2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

txtField2.placeholder = @"Please Select Your Option";

txtField2.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:txtField2];

myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

[myPickerView setDataSource: self];

[myPickerView setDelegate: self];

myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

bloodGroup.inputView = myPickerView;

bloodGroup.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

// txtField1

txtField1.inputView = myPickerView;

txtField1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

txtField2.inputView = myPickerView;

txtField2.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

return 1;

}

else if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected){

return 1;

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

return 1;

}

return 0;

}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

return [dataArray count];

}

else if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected)

{

return [dataArray count];

}

else if (!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

return [dataArray count];

}

return 0;

}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected)

{

return dataArray[row];

}

else if((!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) && (isGenderGroupFieldSelected))

{

return dataArray[row];

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

return dataArray[row];

}

return 0;

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

bloodGroup.text = dataArray[row];

}

else if((!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) && (isGenderGroupFieldSelected))

{

txtField1.text = dataArray[row];

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

txtField2.text= dataArray[row];

}

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

if (textField == bloodGroup) {

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = YES;

}

else if (textField == txtField1){

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;

isGenderGroupFieldSelected = YES;

}

else if (textField == txtField2) {

isGenderGroupFieldSelected = NO;

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;

}

[myPickerView reloadAllComponents];

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

if (textField == bloodGroup) {

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = YES;

}else if (textField == txtField1){

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;

isGenderGroupFieldSelected = YES;

}

else if (textField == txtField2){

isGenderGroupFieldSelected = NO;

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;

}

[myPickerView reloadAllComponents];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[myPickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

}

-(void)done:(id)sender

{

[myPickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; // On 27/04/2020

[bloodGroup resignFirstResponder];

[txtField1 resignFirstResponder];

[txtField2 resignFirstResponder];

}